# Python: NameError when trying to use "re" inside a function

Tags: python

I have a script called `main_plotter.py` that looks like this:

```
import re

import numbs
numbs.getSquares("file.csv")
```

`numbs.py` is the file that I'm importing from. It looks like this:

```
def getSquares(sqfile):
        infile=sqfile
        base_name = re.split(".csv", infile)[0]
        print (base_name)
```

When I run main_plotter.py, I get `NameError: name 're' is not defined`.

Why is this happening? I tried adding `global re` before the `import re` statement, but that doesn't help either. Aren't the import statements supposed to be global anyway? Any help appreciated!

PS. the code runs as expected if I import `re` inside the `numbs.py` file.

Comment: in python, global mean *module level global*, which is a good thing. you seem to expect global global, like C. Or perhaps, you seem to expect that python has dynamic scoping, which is does not, most modern languages use lexical scope. In any case, this is how *all variables work*, you can try something liked `def func(): return x + 2` in one module, and then in another, `from some_module import func; x = 42; print(func())` and you'll see the same behavior

Comment: You need `import re` inside `numbs.py`.

Comment: A module shouldn't require the caller to import the other modules that it depends on.

Comment: Note, from the zen of python (`import this`): "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!" the motivation of this module-global behavior is to keep everything in neat namespaces. true global variables lead to impossible to reason about code for any project that grows large enough and uses more than one programmer (or even just one). You create a minefield of bugs. Work *with* the language, not against it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! @juanpa.arrivillaga and @Barmar Actually I have many modules like `numbs.py` that I need to import and all of them require `re` and a few other python modules. That's why I wanted to know if there is a way to load all the modules at once to avoid having to load them again and again! But looks like that is not possible!

Comment: @PrachitiPrakashPrabhu it may seem like a limitation, but trust me, it will make your overall code better, even if a little bit more redundant at the top of your modules with the imports. unfortunately, true global variables create more problems than they solve, at least, that is the motivation behind this decision. It is similar to the decision made in Go to forgo inheritance completely.

Comment: @PrachitiPrakashPrabhu, to be clear, the second time you `import re`, it uses a cached copy, it doesn't actually spend time/CPU/disk reloading the module. Only the first import does the actual work to load the module, subsequent ones just link the already-loaded module to your current namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Global" in Python means "module namespace". Any `import re` happens exactly there -- *module-by-module*; there intentionally does not exist any wider scope, which ensures that the content of any Python module can be understood by reading only that module (unlike Ruby, where to know the context in which code is run you need to read every module that was ever loaded by the same interpreter).

If you want to use the `re` module in `numbs.py`, you should have a separate `import re` inside that file. This *doesn't* reload the module from disk, but just adds a namespace entry pointing to the already-cached instance that was loaded on first reference.

Comment: the OP knows that this works, they want to understand why their first version doesn't work

Comment: There's a reason this is community-wiki. Feel free to edit. :)